# How can I access the SQLite database from the data folder in the emulator using Android Studio?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to gain access to the SQLite database from the data folder in the Android Device Manager in Android Studio. I am using the Nexus_4_API_24 emulator. When I try and open the data folder nothing opens up as if it is empty. I have searched through hell and still found no answer to problem.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your database doesn't exist

Comment: It does exist because I can add records to it and populate, update and delete from it. I have heard something about not having the correct permissions or something?

Comment: do you mean **Android Device Monitor**?

Comment: Which data folder are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy your database somewhere you know you have access. If memory serves only your application can access the folder /data/data/yourapp/yourdb.sql so unless your file explorer has the specific rights to access this folder, the best idea is to copy it somewhere else.
I know you can copy a file using this, never tested it with a db though,

```
     public static void copyFile(String src, String dst) throws IOException
{
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try
    {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

With src and dst being something like :

```
      src=mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/yourdbname.sql";
      dst=mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath()+"/yourdbname.sql";
```

Then in a file explorer jsut go to sdcard/Android/yourapp/Documents/yourdb.sql

Hope I answered the question and that i could help you